# Entity Framework en Worker Service C# .Net6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dotnetcore

llevo un rato en esto, pero no puedo arreglarlo, no se como pero `EF` no inicializa en un `Worker Service`, he intentado de muchas maneras pero no se puede. es una API de `DotNet Core 6`

```cs
builder.Services.AddDbContext<IDBContext, DBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

// builder.Services.AddSingleton<IRegistra, Registra>();
// builder.Services.AddScoped<IRegistraFactory, RegistraFactory>();
// builder.Services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, Worker>();
```

**Worker**

```cs
namespace ServiceWorker
{
    public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
        public readonly IDBContext _context;

        // private readonly Registra _registra;

        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IDBContext _context)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            // _registra = registra;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                // await _registra.Execute();
                _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
                await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Registra**

```cs
namespace ServiceWorker
{
    public class Registra : IRegistra
    {
        // public readonly IDBContext _context;

        public Registra(IDBContext context)
        // public Registra()
        {
            // _context = context;
        }

        public async Task Execute()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("RUNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN");
            await Task.Delay(5);
        }
    }
}
```

`---> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot consume scoped service 'IDBContext' from singleton 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService'.`

`System.InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: ServiceWorker.Worker': Unable to resolve service for type 'ServiceWorker.Registra' while attempting to activate 'ServiceWorker.Worker'.`

`---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'ServiceWorker.Registra' while attempting to activate 'ServiceWorker.Worker'.`

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varios errores:

- Debes de registrar el servicio IRegistra antes que el worker como AddScoped:

  builder.Services.AddScoped<IRegistra, Registra>()
- El Worker debes de registrarlo como Scoped, ya que un DBContext siempre se registra como Scoped y no singleton.